# assigning value from sql request of type datetime into java.util.Date variable

Tags: java, sql, date, datetime, time

I tried this..

```
MCorr mc = new MCorr();
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM mcorr");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
while(rs.next()){
    mc.setDateMaint(rs.getDate("dateMaint"));
}
```

then this

```
MCorr mc = new MCorr();
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM mcorr");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
 while(rs.next()){
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM");
    java.util.Date date = sdf1.parse(rs.getString("dateMaint"));
    java.sql.Date sqlDate = new Date(date.getTime()); 
    mc.setDateMaint(sqlDate );
}
```

but any way it only shows the date without hours and minutes..

in MCorr class
 `private Date dateMaint;`

what should I do to get the date and time ..

Comment: Do you have time stored along with date in database? What is the type of `"dateMaint"` column in the table?

Comment: @DarshanMehta yes I have, and the type of dateMaint in database is datetime